# How to delete a row using laravel 5.6 on an InnoDB engine?

Tags: php, laravel, innodb

I'm building a simple project management web app and I have InnoDB as my tables engine and apparently I can't delete a "company" owning at least on project so I tried to handle the this case using appropriate error messages display.

My goal is to display tell the user that the company can't be deleted if the company has projects and I've succeeded doing that except that when I've deleted all the projects of that specific company from the database I still get the same message "Company has projects..."

```
 */
public function destroy(Company $company)
{
    $current = Company::find($company->id);        

    if($current !== null){
        $companiesProjects = $current->projects;

        if($companiesProjects === null){
            if($current->delete()){
                return redirect()->route('companies.index')
                ->with('success', 'Company has been successfully deleted!');
            }
        }else{
            return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Company has projects... it can\'t be deleted!');
        }
    }else{
        return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Company does not exist!');

    }

   return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Company could not be deleted!');
}
}
```

I've tried another solution which is to use the Project object inside of the function after adding it's namespace to the resource controller but unluckily my php server stops running and my PC stops responding and I have no other choice but restarting PC

```
 public function destroy(Company $company, Project $project)
     {
        $current = Company::find($company->id);

    if($current !== null){
        $companiesProjects = Project::where('company_id', $company->id);

        if($companiesProjects === null){
           /* if($current->delete()){
                //return redirect()->route('companies.index')
                //->with('success', 'Company has been successfully deleted!');
            }*/
            echo 'null';
        }else{
            //return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Company has projects... it can\'t be deleted!');
        }
    }else{
        //return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Company does not exist!');

    }

   //return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Company could not be deleted!');
}
```

I'm only following a video course and I'm lost in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$company->projects` will return an array. Either a filled one or an empty one. But either way `$company->projects === null` will return false.

You should just do:

```
if(!$current->projects->count()) {
    // Empty
} else {
    // Not empty
}
```

May I also interest you in some cleaner logic?

```
if ($company->projects->isNotEmpty()) {
    return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Company has projects... it can\'t be deleted!');
}
if (!$company->delete()) {
    return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Company could not be deleted!');
}
return redirect()->route('companies.index')
            ->with('success', 'Company has been successfully deleted!');
```

The `$current = Company::find($company->id)` is unneeded. Since you're using model binding, the `$company` will either be an instance alreaady, or the route will return a `404`, which also removes the need for the first `if` block.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code and thanks for the cleaner code. Unlickily I still have the same message "Company has projects... it can't be deleted!". I believe the condition is faulty and there must be a function that returns a boolean instead.
Other than that I have my errors variable set by default on the "companies.index" that display an empty error window with no message on it but an opening and a closing bracket "[]". Extremely weird...

Comment: Hmm yes, you're right. An empty collection still returns true. You could do `if(!$current->projects->count())` instead. This one I tested

Comment: Or even more explicit [`->isNotEmpty()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-isnotempty): `if ($current->projects->isNotEmpty())`

Comment: You actually win! Except for the funny fact that I still have the brackets couple appearing under the success message. What do you think causes this ?

Comment: @HamzaELjaouhari Not sure what you mean. Btw, just noticed that you're doing 1 too many database calls, you're using model binding, which means the `$company` will already find the Company by the passed `id` or return a 404